# UIView in UIView issue

Tags: iphone, uiview, bounds

Perhaps I'm missing a property or misunderstanding something but having issues with something simple.

I have a UIView with a frame lets say of 100px high in which I have another UIView with lets say 50px high. If set the main UIView to 20px high the 50px high one is fully visible. I thought it might of been something to do with the bounds so I set that and its no different.

Sorry if this is answered somewhere else but couldn't find anything relating to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the "parent" view, set the `clipsToBounds` property to YES.

Comment: bleh, knew it was something simple.